# How to convert a page object to DTOs?

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have a page object like the following, how to convert it to a DTO?

```
Page<Post> latestPosts = postRepo.findAll(firstPageWithTwoElements);
```

Comment: I'm sure this is mistagged.. what language is this? c#?

Comment: It is java. To be specifical it is spring boot framework.

Comment: ah.. thought it might be java (given `findAll` method).. but I was taken back by your term.. I believe java developers use terms like POJO and projections to reflect on the concept of creating DTOs from entities.. essentially you're going to ***map*** to new instances of your DTO type.

Comment: You can use latestPosts.getContent() to get the Entity on which Pagination is enabled.

Comment: here is interesting external link for you to review @imikay https://www.baeldung.com/entity-to-and-from-dto-for-a-java-spring-application take a look at the Sevice Layer and Controller layer (for the `convertToDto` portion)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the following line will do the trick:

return latestPosts.stream().map(post -> postMapper.postToPostDto(post)).collect(Collectors.toList());